# NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, memory-leaks, nsevent

Here again with another memory leak issue. I have an NSStatusItem that I'm trying to capture mouse clicks on and react. The following code causes Instruments to report a leak and removing this code causes Instruments to report no leaks:

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDown | NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDown | NSRightMouseDownMask)
                                              handler:^NSEvent *(NSEvent *event)
         {
             if (event.window == self.statusItem.button.window)
             {
                 [self statusItemClicked:self.statusItem.button];
                 return nil;
             }
             return event;
         }];
```

Advice on how to properly implement this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image: Instruments Leak]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` method returns the monitor object. You can pass the object to `removeMonitor:` when you no longer need it and want the system to stop sending events to it.

The event monitor creates a retain cycle involving itself. This keeps the monitor alive even if you don't keep a reference to the monitor. This retain cycle is showing up as leaked objects in Instruments.

If you want to prevent the leaks from showing up in Instruments, store the monitor (returned by `addLocalMonitor...`) somewhere, like in an instance variable on your app delegate.

Comment: This works perfectly. I added a @property NSEvent instance variable and all is well. Thanks Rob!

Comment: It would be more correct to make the property's type `id`, not `NSEvent`, because the return object is not an `NSEvent`.